# Json.Net library JsonConvert

Tags: json.net

I'm using http://json.codeplex.com library. I'm trying to convert XML to JSON and vice-versa.

However they have an example using `JsonConvert` class

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

I can't find `JsonConvert` in namespace `Newtonsoft.Json`. I've only found class `JavaScriptConvert`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

You have an old version of Json.NET. JavaScriptConvert was renamed to JsonConvert a couple of years ago.

Comment: Hello James. Does JSON.net requires .net 3.5 sp1 or can it work on .net 2.0? I used your library to serialize an XML node but i got an error. But installing .net 3.5 sp1 fixed the issue. In the requirements page i see .net 2.0 mentioned. Any ideas?